# How come CCF function in R return different correlation for same vectors ie. corr(x,y) and corr(y,x)

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

```
set.seed(1)
sample = rnorm(20,mean = 5,1)
x=acf(ts.intersect(ts(sample),ts(sample+.5*sample)))
```

When we look at the output for the above code, 
x[1,2] , corr between x,y and x[2,1] corr between y,x , it gives a different answer.

x[1,2]!=x[2,1] ; what am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the plot, perhaps you are missing the lag values: upper right plot has lags 0,...,10, while lower left one has lags -10,...,0. Then indeed *i* and -*i* lags coincide for i=0,...,10.

In terms of the `x` object,

```
x[2,1]

# Autocorrelations of series ‘ts.intersect(ts(sample), ts(sample + 0.5 * sample))’, by lag
#
#      2 
# -0.185 
x[1,2]

# Autocorrelations of series ‘ts.intersect(ts(sample), ts(sample + 0.5 * sample))’, by lag
#
#      1 
# -0.122
```

so that the first one corresponds to lag ±2, while the second one is lag ±1.

Comment: Thanks, its clear now. x$acf is an array (not a matrix) ; so x[1,2] was a correlation at lag 1 and x[2,1] is correlation at lag 2

Comment: @Yash, right. Also, while `x$acf` is indeed an array, it's not immediately clear which element of this array `x[1,2]` is, because `x$acf` is three dimensional (hence we need three indices), so it really seems to be a better idea to subset `x$acf` instead.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it got confusing. Thanks for clarification.